# R Shiny Dynamic text in header (reactive renderUI)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to put dynamic text in shiny's header, and have managed to put text in it, but cannot get it to update after it has received new data from an reactive expression. To put text in the header, I have used a basic Java call, **tags$script**.

My concern is that renderUI only renders the 1st time, and does not force render whenever the reactive value (val) is updated, which is exactly what I require.

Apologies for the weird example below, I have a HUGE dashboard which has several chained dependencies, and I have tried to replicate the types of dependencies in the reproducible example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dashboardPage(skin = 'black',
                  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
                  dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id = 'MenuTabs',
                                  menuItem("dummy", tabName = "rawanalysis", selected = TRUE, icon = icon("dashboard"))
                      )
                  ),
    dashboardBody(
        uiOutput(outputId = 'Header'),
        fluidRow(
            box(
                actionButton("change", "Change")
            )
    ))))


server <- function(input, output) {

    Go_rv <- reactiveValues(val = 0)
    observeEvent(input$change, {

        sam <- rnorm(1)

        if(sam > 0){
            Go_rv$val <- TRUE
        } else {
            Go_rv$val <- FALSE
        }

    })

    val <- reactive({
        print(Go_rv$val)
        if(Go_rv$val){

            out <- 0
        } else {
            out <- -5
        }    

        return(out)


    })

    output$Header <- renderUI({

        removeUI(
            selector = "div:has(> #Header)"
        )

        header_text <- paste0('$(document).ready(function() {
                              $("header").find("nav").append(\'<div class="myClass">', val(), '</div>\');})')

        tags$script(HTML(header_text),
                    id = 'Header'
        )
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically, a `reactive` text output with `observeEvent` should do this job!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(skin = 'black',
                dashboardHeader(title = textOutput('test')),
                dashboardSidebar(
                  sidebarMenu(id = 'MenuTabs',
                              menuItem("dummy", tabName = "rawanalysis", selected = TRUE, icon = icon("dashboard"))
                  )
                ),
                dashboardBody(
                  #uiOutput(outputId = 'Header'),
                  fluidRow(
                    box(
                      actionButton("change", "Change")
                    )
                  ))))


server <- function(input, output,session) {


  title_change <- reactive({
    input$change
    as.character(Sys.time())
  })


observeEvent(input$change, { output$test <- renderText({ title_change()

})
})


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi amrss, maybe I forgot to mention that the solution MUST stay in the center of the header, which is why I have used the tags$script part. When trying your solution with this tag, I get an error.

Comment: @Sharma When you mean center, do you want it in the sidebar or in the right side?

Comment: If you don't need sidebar then the simpler solution is ```dashboardHeader(title = textOutput('test'),titleWidth = 1050)```

Comment: Yes, I do not need a sidebar header. The solution somewhat works, but now I have a very weird URL and have lost the ability to change colours and fonts, which I had before. Do you know how I can fix the URL and change the font style?

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean by weird URL? And changing colors of the dashboard? Can you be please more specific?

Comment: After I open the app in browser mode, the tab text has '<div....' etc in it (top of the window), which I believe will remain upon hosting a live app. Secondly, I am yet to figure out how but is there a clean way to change the text color? Also I'm giving +1 for your answer as it does work :)